# Python Data Science Imputation. Index with two or more NaN values

Tags: python, data-science, nan, imputation

I want to use a linear regression model on my data. However, some columns have NaN values, and I dont know how to go about it.

| Index | F_1 | F_2 | F_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.5 | 1.5 - | 1 |
| 1 | 0.8 | 2.3 | 2 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| 3 | 1.2 | 3.0 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | 1.9 | 1.4 |
| 5 | 0.7 | NaN | 1.6 |
| 6 | 1 | 2.6 | 2.2 |

To fit the data, I could delete the columns with NaN values:

| Index | F_1 | F_2 | F_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.5 | 1.5 - | 1 |
| 1 | 0.8 | 2.3 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2.6 | 2.2 |

But I want to keep all my data and still be able to process it. How do I handle the columns with NaN values?

Comment: You can impute the data with `mean, mode or median` according to your need or you can drop `nan` values. From given snippet of 6 rows you can try with `mean` or `median`. You can refer [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/dealing-with-missing-values-in-python-a-complete-guide/#:~:text=If%20there%20is%20a%20certain,row%20with%20%60NaN%60%20values.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Usually column median is a good value to substitute if you know the missing is random. However, if you believe that the `F_2` missing at index 2 is different from the `F_2` missing at index 5, you can use a linear regression between just `F_2` and `F_3`.

Comment: Please post this question to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okey, i already posted there. But i have a question. So, if i have 50+ columns, and 30 columns ( https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/tabular-playground-series-jun-2022 ) have NaN values then i need to make linear regression or another model between every 2-3 columns? I need very much memory to calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Pandas, the solution would be to use only row with valid values. That means you have to omit all rows with NaN values.

```
filtered_df = df.dropna()
```

An alternative would be to replace NaN with some reasonable value, e.g. the average of the column. This can be helpful if you have many columns and only some have missing values.

Comment: Thank you. But i know how to drop NaN values. I mean, that I already do it and have model to predict, but this model needs to input two columns to predict third. But in case with the second index I have two columns with NaN, so I can't use this model to predict third column.

Comment: Okay, understood. I suggest that you replace NaN Values before training the model with some reasonable value and apply the same strategy to your input data when you are using the model.